# Stackblitz: Vue + Vuetify + Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuetify.js, stackblitz

Is there a way to use Stackblitz for development with vue3, vuetify and firebase auth? Here is what I got so far: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-xwk34s?file=src/main.js

**Vuetify**

I added vuetify as dependency and followed the instruction from their official documentation.

This is the code in ***main.js***:

```
const { createApp } = require('vue');
import App from './App.vue';

// Vuetify
import 'vuetify/styles';
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify';
import * as components from 'vuetify/components';
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives';

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
});

createApp(App).use(vuetify).mount('#app');
```

But I get the error:

> Error in /~/src/main.js (33:19)
> Cannot use import statement outside a module

My thought was, if it has something to because the dependencies are being installed to "turbo_modules", but I am stuck with getting further.

**Firebase auth**
Most difficult might be firebase auth, is it even possible? Because I can connect it as a deployment location, but for auth I would have to use the terminal to login to my project, right? I don't have a terminal in Stackblitz. Or is there any other way?

Thanks a lot!

Kind regards
Tim

Comment: stackblitz automatic dependency tracking seems off.  both vite and webpack being dependencies is a weird red flag.  I think the vite+vue stackblitz environment is a better one to start with: https://vite.new/vue.  You will need to add packages from the command line and rerun the project with `yarn dev` but it should work for installing vuetify

Comment: Thanks, that's working for the vue.js and vuetify part!

Comment: Any ideas on how to initialize firebase login on Stackblitz? The authentication link doesnt work because it redirects to localhost.

`firebase login --no-localhost` just doesn't do anything, same as `firebase :ci`